# Akka Stream stages not executing concurrently

Tags: akka-stream

I'm starting to learn Akka Streams and am running the first example from here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-rate.html#stream-rate-scala

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  Source(1 to 10)
  .map { i => println(s"A: $i"); i }
  .map { i => println(s"B: $i"); i }
  .map { i => println(s"C: $i"); i }
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)

}
```

Based on the example, the output should be non-deterministic like this:

```
A: 1
A: 2
B: 1
A: 3
B: 2
C: 1
B: 3
C: 2
C: 3
```

But when I run it, it never starts processing the next element until the previous is fully processed.

```
A: 1
B: 1
C: 1
A: 2
B: 2
C: 2
A: 3
B: 3
C: 3
A: 4
B: 4
C: 4
A: 5
B: 5
C: 5
A: 6
B: 6
C: 6
A: 7
B: 7
C: 7
A: 8
B: 8
C: 8
A: 9
B: 9
C: 9
A: 10
B: 10
C: 10
```

I also tried adding a delay into each stage/map (with Thread.sleep), and only one thing was processed at a time, as if the actor system only has one thread. I was able to confirm that the Akka dispatcher has enough threads.

```
  import system.dispatcher
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

  ( 1 to 10 ).map { i => Future { Thread.sleep( 1000 ); println( s"Finished ${i} after ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}ms" ) }
```

Output:

```
Finished 5 after 1004ms
Finished 2 after 1004ms
Finished 6 after 1005ms
Finished 8 after 1004ms
Finished 4 after 1004ms
Finished 9 after 1005ms
Finished 7 after 1004ms
Finished 3 after 1005ms
Finished 1 after 1006ms
Finished 10 after 1009ms
```

Does something need to be tweaked to get the stages to process concurrently?

I'm using Akka Streams 2.4.2 and Java 1.8.0_65-b17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, that you're observing an [Operator Fusion](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#Operator_Fusion), which means that all three `map` operations are being executed on the same Actor.

The fusable elements are for example:

- all GraphStages (this includes all built-in junctions apart from groupBy)
- all Stages (this includes all built-in linear operators)
- TCP connections

You can either disable it either by passing configuration parameter `akka.stream.materializer.auto-fusing=off` which disables it completely (I'm not sure its a good idea in general) or you can disable it in your code by adding async boundaries (see the link I've attached for more details). Everything in a single async boundary gets executed on a single actor.

```
Source(1 to 10)
  .map { i => println(s"A: $i"); i }.async
  .map { i => println(s"B: $i"); i }.async
  .map { i => println(s"C: $i"); i }.async
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it. I guess they haven't gotten around to updating the docs for the example I was testing, because Operator Fusion changes that behavior. Thanks again!

Comment: @voipdaddy fyi: there already is an issue for updating the documentation: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20017.